# What is the origin of the use of "Lorem ipsum ..." as a placeholder in web design?

Tags: meaning, etymology, latin

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) pretty much sums up the meaning of this gobbledegook, a mangling of 1st century Latin, but fails to explain WHY variations on this particular filler are used as placeholders on many web site templates.

> ....Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure....

Pretty good, philosophically speaking, if you ask me. But what in the name of Shakespearean eloquence has it got to do with modern Web Design?

Comment: This is about the history and practice of design, not English, so it's probably more appropriate at [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off topic

Comment: just click vote to close

Comment: The question in the title is off-topic. The question in the question body is different than the title and it is unclear. Are you asking why the English translation is used? Is the English translation ever used in websites?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with the English language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [www.lipsum.com](http://www.lipsum.com/):

> - ***Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,*** when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. ***It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,*** and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Its popularity in the past centuries was due to the fact that is was used in:

> - "*de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"* (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. and  ***this book , a treatise on the theory of ethics, was  very popular during the Renaissance.***

As for current web usage:

> - It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. ***The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.***  Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

Comment: That's true. But it still doesn't explain that out of millions of ancient texts why only *Lorem ipsum* became the canon for dummy text? Why not Othello or Aesop's Fables for that matter?

Comment: Are you asking about its diffusion in history or about it as  a standard in web design?

Comment: @PrahladYeri: Someone started it and other people took it up. Precisely because it has no meaning, as a dummy, there's no need to replace it with any other text. Why go to the bother of finding another text with a normal letter distribution? _Othello_ would have been no good in English typesetting, since it is readable and distracting. It was also written in 1604, so would not have been around in the 1500s.

Comment: Everyone knows why that guy first did it in the 1500s, he just went to the obvious URL http://loremipsum.com

Answer (score 3):

Your question header asks one thing ("What is the origin of the use of “Lorem ipsum …” as a placeholder in web design?") and your body-copy question asks another ("WHY [is it that] variations on this particular filler are used as placeholders on many web site templates[?]")—but since Josh61 provides a thorough answer to the question of origin, I'll focus on the question of practical purpose.

One feature of modern periodicals—especially in print, but to some extent online as well—is the fragmentary nature of much of the content, owing to the use of multiple captions, infographics, labeled illustrations, tables, sidebars, and mini-TOCs, among other elements. In a dummy layout, the actual wording of these various elements may not be known, but the designer still wants to see—and show—how the layout will look when words are in place; so in goes "Lorem ipsum dolor..." wherever text will appear.

Having created a dummy layout, the designer may pass the layout to an editor to swap out the dummy text with the content intended for publication, or the designer may receive that content from the editor and pour the actual content into the layout him- or herself. It is not at all uncommon for whoever is swapping out the dummy text to miss pieces of it here and there—in a caption, say, or in an illustration label (since entering each label is a separate operation).

Not only does "Lorem ipsum dolor..." stand out from actual story text by virtue of its foreignness, but it triggers red flags near the end of the process when the proofreader runs an automated spelling check after completing the human proofreading.

This is a crucial advantage over using real English text such as "Caption goes here caption goes here caption goes here." I remember reading an issue of *ESPN: The Magazine* (probably 15 years ago) in which a nice action photo of a basketball player swooping in for a dunk was accompanied by a caption that said something like this:

> The purple rhinoceros opens his yellow umbrella to gather raspberries.

A page later, a shot of another player bore the same caption. Clearly, the editors at the magazine had decided that the "purple rhinoceros" language was at least as eye-catching as "Lorem ipsum dolor" and had elected to make it the dummy text for placeholder captions. But this time around, a proofreader had neglected to check the captions at all—and the automated spelling checker (assuming that the proofreader ran it) hadn't found anything objectionable in the dummy text.

With regard to Web design, it's less embarrassing to have purple rhinoceroses on a published page online than in a published page in print, since it's never too late to correct errors in online content. Nevertheless, it is still very useful to be able to search for, find, and replace shards of dummy text in a layout quickly and exhaustively before making the Web page go live.

Comment: Actually, the question body also had the same thing, but was later edited by someone as you can see. It originally said: **The Wikipedia article pretty much sums up the meaning of this 1st century Latin gobbledegook, but fails to explain WHY its used as placeholder on many web site templates?**